# VueJS data return array not reactive with template

Tags: javascript, vue.js, socket.io

I'm making a chat system for admin and clients using VueJS and socket.io. When a client connects to the server and entered a name, it should add a new row in the admin chats with the client's name. And when they disconnect it should be removed from the list of admin chats. But that doesn't work. I have to force reload the page then the chat is gone.

Template:

```
    <div class="chats" id="chat"  v-if="chats.length >= 1">
        <div class="chat" v-for="chat in chats">
            <b>{{ chat.clientName }}</b>
            <p>ID: {{ chat.clientID }}</p>
            <div class="jens-button">
                <img src="/icons/chat-bubble.svg">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="chats" v-else>
        <div class="chat">
            <b>There are no chats avaiable.</b>
        </div>
    </div>
```

data:

```
        data() {
            return {
                chats: [],
            }
        },


        method() {                                           
            socket.on('update clients', (clients) => {
                console.log(clients);
                this.chats = [];
                if(clients.length >= 1) {
                    this.chats = clients;
                } else {
                    this.chats = [];
                }
            });
        }
```

What goes wrong? If someone finds the answer, can you also give me an explanation why it isn't working? Thank you!

Comment: Try and get rid of the socket.on() inside the methods and computed. There is no need to constantly declare it over and over again. You might do it once on `mounted()`

Comment: @Rie, then it still won't update the template v-for

Comment: Correct but that was the first step to make it less confusing on what's going on. Please update your post with the new code that you got going on now. Also, why is the code existing once as a method and once as a computed? They do pretty much the same thing, hmm. You'd only need the method in your case

Comment: Oke, I updated it now to this

Answer (score 2):

The way you got it right now is not a valid way to declare [methods](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/#Handling-User-Input) in Vue. This way your `socket.on` never gets declared. Please make use of `mounted()`. You can read more about the lifecycles of components [here](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/instance.html#Lifecycle-Diagram).

A barebones example would be the following. Also make sure to add a `:key` to your `v-for`.

```html
<div class="chats" id="chat"  v-if="chats.length >= 1">
        <div class="chat" v-for="chat in chats" :key="chat.clientID">
```

```js
data() {
  return {
    chats: [],
  }
},
mounted() {
  socket.on('update clients', (clients) => {
    // You could also declare a dedicated method for this instead of doing it inline
    console.log(clients);
    if(clients.length >= 1) {
      this.chats = clients;
    } else {
      this.chats = [];
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: Yea I changed it to that now. But the v-for in the template still shows the clients that were connected but now disconnected. But they are still in  the v-for template list.

Comment: Does the `console.log(clients)` show the correct data? Do you get any errors in your console?

Comment: Yea I get the correct clients in the console.log, no errors but the HTML is not changing.

Comment: I updated the post, please try and add the :key to your loop as described

Comment: Still not worling, everything is fine the this.chats array is filled but the HTML only updates when I force reload the webbrowser

Comment: But the console.log actually triggers whenever the server emits a socket-event, right? As it stands the code waits for the socket-server to emit "update clients". Only then the code gets executed

Comment: When the emit “update clients” gets executed the console.log works and the this.chats variable  only the HTML not

Comment: Im sorry I do not see the issue. The code should work just fine. Maybe someone else sees the mistake..

Comment: Hmm, thank you for helping ! I will trie to figure it out